# Internal error 500 when trying to add a user in Cakephp 3.6

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0, addition

Hello I'm going crazy trying to add a user to the database.

When I add the line:

```
$adduser = $this->Users->patchEntity($adduser, $this->request->getdata());
```

Gives me the error:

> Internal Server Error [500].

If I comment on this line, then the record is not saved.

I checked the form, in case I wasn't putting all the database fields right, but it's okay. I checked it.

I don't know what could be wrong.

```
public function add() {
  $idepersonas = TableRegistry::get('Personas')->find('all')
                                               ->select(['Personas.id','Personas.nombre', 'Personas.primer_apellido', 'Personas.segundo_apellido'])
                                               ->orderAsc('Personas.nombre', 'Personas.primer_apellido');

  $adduser = $this->Users->newEntity();

  if($this->request->is('post')) {
    debug($adduser);
    debug($this->request->getdata());
    $adduser = $this->Users->patchEntity($adduser, $this->request->getdata());
    //debug($this->request->getdata());

    if($this->Users->save($adduser)) {

      $this->Flash->success('El usuario ha sido creado correctamente', [
        'key' => 'positive',
        'params' => ['nombre' => $adduser->nombre]
      ]);

      $tabler = "users";
      $idUser = $adduser->id;
      return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Imagenes', 'action' => 'add', 'idUser' => $idUser, 'tabler' => $tabler]);
    }
    else {
      debug($adduser);
      echo "No funciona";
      $this->Flash->error(__('El usuario no pudo ser creado. Por favor, intentelo de nuevo.'));
    }
  }

  $data = [
           'idepersonas' => $idepersonas,
           'adduser' => $adduser
            ];
  $this->set($data);
}
```

Clarification:

The user can not register if it does not exist in a previous list, that is the reason for the consultation $idepersonas but is not important, for which I ask, only so that it does not lead to confusion.

In the end what I did instead of passing all the data in the form, I passed them from one to one with:

```
$isData = $this->request->getdata();
...
$adduser->email = $isData['email'];
$adduser->password = $isData['password'];
...
```

Until I get to the password, when I pass the password, that's when I get error 500, I think the encryption doesn't do it correctly, I have in the User entity:

```
protected function _setPassword($password) {
       if (strlen($password) > 0) {
           return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
       }
       else {
         $id_user = $this->properties['id'];
         user = TableRegistry::get('Users')->recoverPassword($id_user);
         return $user;
       }
   }

protected $_hidden = ['password'];
```

Comment: Ok, I discovered something, that the variable $ adduser returns empty of the form and I do not know why: Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() must be an instance of Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, null given

Comment: Is the `newEntity` call returning `null`? It certainly shouldn't be. Perhaps `$this->User` is of a type that's somehow had the `newEntity` function replaced? Can't think what else might cause this.

Comment: Enable debug mode by making `'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),` in `app.php`. It will give you exact error instead of 500 only. Then please give your error message here.

Comment: oohh I already have it enabled by default.

Comment: The problem is with the encryption of the password, I add data in the question.

Comment: Solved! In the User entity, I need to add:

`use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher; `